# API documentation for tezos.org.sg?

Tags: api

I saw that one can use API from tezos.org.sg, for example https://node1.lax.tezos.org.sg:8080/v0/block/. However I'm having hard time finding  documentation for that API. tzscan's API is not a problem to find documentation and use, but what about tezos.org.sg?

Answer (score 1):

Tezos.ID's APIs should exist already, but are not yet available for public use.  See https://tezos.id/roadmap saying that they will be released around the end of July 2019.